# Folder-level group-based access for NFS directories

Tags: amazon-efs

We have an AWS EFS called efs 1. We want to map it to a directory in Linux named /data. Under this, will be subdirectories sd1, sd2, sd3 and so on.

We would like Linux group1 to access sd1 and sd2, group2 to access sd2 and sd3, etc. This means we would like to give group-based access to the contents of the EFS.

EFS does not support ACL.

How can we achieve the folder-level group-based access?